# Stumped by FileNotFound exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

All I want to do is import data from a text file.  The file exists at C:\temp\text.txt.  However, I keep getting a file not found error.  What the heck am I doing wrong???

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String mFilename = "C:\\temp\\text.txt";
    Scanner myDataStream = new Scanner(new File(mFilename));}
```

Comment: Is `C:\\temp\\temp.txt` the ACTUAL file? Or your example.

Comment: Googling brought up a case where someone had file extensions hidden and his file was actually `text.txt.txt`. Check if it's not your case.

Comment: glowcoder - it was just the example name.  Vache - you were right it was caused by Windows 7 obscuring the true file ending so the file was actually text.txt.txt.  I'm still adjusting to Windows 7 :(

Comment: @Michael: you can change settings so that Windows 7 shows all file extensions.

Comment: @Hovercraft - yes I know.  My previous computer had Vista and I had to do the same thing.  Just got the new one and forgot to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of giving this question an answer:

Googling brought up a case where someone had file extensions hidden and his file was actually `text.txt.txt`. Check if it's not your case.

You can display extensions in Windows 7 by going in `Organize > Folder and search option > View` and unchecking `Hide extensions for known file types` from any folder's menu.