# groovy File not found error when file exists

Tags: groovy

I am trying to access a file on my computer using the following code:

```
new File('c:/test.txt').eachLine{
line->println line
}
```

I know the file exists, why do I see an error that the file is not found. Is this maybe an issue with my groovy install?

Comment: My file had a two extensions on it. Answered by this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409971/stumped-by-filenotfound-exception

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the code or your groovy installation.

Recheck the file extension. If you are on Windows 7, the file extensions might be hidden while viewed in the Windows Explorer.

Also, it is better to respect the case sensitivity of filenames, if in case you are working on a Linux machine (which I assume not).

Or perhaps it could also have something to do with file permissions if in case your stack trace looks like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass JMS params (-Xms -Xmx etc.) to the groovy command you would get that result. You can find the full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459317/how-do-i-increase-groovys-jvm-heap-size).